# monitoring stand alone application

Tags: c#, sockets, monitoring, health-monitoring

I have some stand alone console application in c#.net,and I'm going to create a project for control and monitor these application,what is best solution for this purpose?
Can I create socket programming project as server application and my console application as client subscribe to server application?

Comment: Ofc, it is possible. Like several different solutions too. Please give use more details.

Comment: consider each client has some ability such as start,stop,error logging,... I wanna to control these client from master apllication,Start and stop with master application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that less details, I think windows [services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be the best chose for the clients. You are able to control them remotely (start, stop) and also you could use custom commands for special tasks. Additional to that, you are able to check the service status and get further information. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you find some information about the service control methods.